# Debian Bullseye gets DHCP address instead of static after first boot

Tags: networking, debian, dhcp

After a cold start, the NIC gets an IP-address from DHCP, not the static IP-adress that is defined in /etc/network/interfaces. After a warm boot, it gets the correct static IP-address. I have got a bunch of other computers (virtual and physical) with Debian Bullseye installed, and it's the first time ever I see this behavior. On this device, a static IP-address is mandatory. Hardware and OS information below.

No fancy networking, just standard Debian configuration.

I would be very grateful for any information that can help me solve this annoying problem.

Best regards,

Peter

**Hardware**

CPU: AMD Ryzen 5700G
Chipset: AMD X570
NIC: Realtek RTL8125 2.5GbE
WiFi: disabled in BIOS
RAM: 2x8GB, 4000MHz, XMP Profile 1
Drive: Seagate Firecuda 4TB, NVMe 4.0

**OS**
Debian Bullseye 11.2, frequently updated

Comment: Why is DHCP even set up at all if it must not be used in this system? // Perhaps compare the `dmesg` output of cold and warm boot. You could use normal diff tools (GUI or otherwise) to do that.

Comment: Is setting the IP as a static DCHP reservation with your DHCP server a possibility? If so, it would be one less thing to (remember to) reconfigure if you ever need to reinstall, keeps the IP the same if you need to start in rescue mode, and if every system you need having static IPs on the network is configured via that DHCP server, that is a set of configuration being kept in a single place. (if not an option, such as if you are not an admin of the DHCP server on your network, or this system needs to always be the same IP regardless of network connected, could you add your interfaces file?)

Comment: @Daniel B: The network is setup the standard Debian way through /etc/network/interfaces. It's not possible to remove the dhcp-client package. I will have a look what dmesg tells me. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @FreelancerJ: Yes, I could create a reservation, but I'm reluctant to create specific remedies for things that really should work. I prefer to nail the problem and solve it where it occurs. There are around 400 different network devices connected, and fixes need documentation and administration. I save fixes for critical stuff. Thanks for your input.

Comment: DHCP doesn’t just activate on its own, even if installed. That’s why I’m asking. Did you perhaps enable _systemd-networkd_ with conflicting configuration options?

Comment: @DanielB: No, I did not enable systemd-networkd. I also checked that it's disabled. On Debian I stick to the default network configuration methods. Very clear and simple to setup. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I succeeded nailing the problem down. For some reason connman was installed. I have got no idea how that happened, probably it was pulled in by some other package. After removing connman, there is just the defined IP-address for the interface.

The conclusion is, don't install connman. Remove connman if it gets installed. I sincerely hate components that do their own stuff behind the back without configuration and without announcing themselves. It's a source of problems and a big pain.